# How do I establish my vocal range, and extend it without hurting myself?

Tags: voice

I am 17 years old and I have a little deep voice in my age right now. My vocal break is in F4, so I'm very confused and have problems in my voice when singing because I don't know if I'm destroying my voice. It's all because I can hit low notes like F1 (my lowest note) and also I can hit high notes like F5 (but I can only sing that higher if I'm using mixed register and singing pop songs).

Problems:

- When I sing in my chest register I can only hit G4 with breath support. Can I still extend this range up higher?
- Mixed Voice is what register I use mostly in high notes but when I'm switching my voice from chest to mix like F4 to G4. That G4 note is very soft, weak, and still flipping down to my chest voice. I don't really know what my true vocal break is.
- I can sing very low notes also, but I don't really want to become a bass singer. What I want is to become a tenor and can hit G5.
- Sometimes when I am practicing some songs that has C5 as the highest note, it feels like an intensive song for my body, because I always feel a little pain in my jaw, back, neck, and in my chest. Is that good for me?

Comment: I think this is the kind of question only a vocal teacher can answer you. He will tell you what type your voice is and how to extend you range appropriately. By the way, I don't see how the title relates to the question....?

Comment: Down voting and voting to close are two separate functions, and the tooltios explain when they should be used. I often do one without the other.

Answer (score 1):

You will always be able to extend your vocal range with the correct training. Doing this incorrectly though can be very harmful, and to do it properly I'd recommend one-on-one professional training. If you can't afford (or don't want to do) this, there are plenty of online tutorials and exercises to help you extend your vocal range if you're tenacious and proper about self-studying.

Regarding "becoming" different types of singers, you will always naturally fit one type of voice more than others and in my experience this doesn't ever change once you've settled into your adult voice. Having said this, you're still young and developing so it'll probably be a few more years before your voice truly settles.

And what's wrong with being a bass anyway? Basses are great! Plus there are many basses and baritones who spend most of their professional singing careers up in the stratosphere (first example coming to mind being someone like Chris Cornell who was a natural baritone but is best known for his incredibly high vocal range). Plus these are more like *guidelines* anyway - every voice is unique, and classifying them as things like "bass" or "tenor" just helps with finding songs probably in that singer's range.

Regarding your last question, if you are straining to hit high notes to the point where it is uncomfortable, you are not singing correctly. You should never feel uncomfortable with proper technique. This does come with practice, but make sure you've not developed any bad habits. Again, a professional singing teacher can help with this.

---

For extra reading (listening/watching?): videos like [this one](https://youtu.be/mNppbS_p5qA) (What Voice Type Am I?) can be a good starting point for establishing what you can most comfortably sing and where you can go from there.